# Why does tangent not exist at point $(0,0)$ of the curve $(x,y) = (t^3,t^5),~~ t\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: curves, tangent-line, parametrization

Given the curve $(x,y) = (t^3,t^5)$, why does such parametrisation does not give the tangent at $(0,0)$? and why would other parametrisation give a valid tangent? What would be such a valid paramatrization?

Comment: Well, any curve that has a tangent everywhere should be isomorphic to the line. Can you think of a bijection from the curve to the real line?

Comment: Can you define what you want a "tangent" to be for the curve $(t^3, t^5)$? What property do you want to be satisfied?  I observe via implicit differentiation that $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt} = \frac{5t^4}{3t^2}\rightarrow 0 \quad \mbox{ as } t\rightarrow 0^+$$ and $0$ is a valid slope for a tangent line. I assume we are dealing with $t \geq 0$, you could also write the curve as $\{(x, x^{5/3}) : x \geq 0\}$.

Comment: The implicit equation is $x^5-y^3=0$, which has tangent cone $y^3=0$ at the origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your curve can also be parametrized as $(x,x^{\frac{5}{3}})$, so it is the graph of a $C^1$ function $f(x)\colon x\mapsto x^{\frac{5}{3}}$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. The derivative $f'(x) = \frac{5}{3} x^{\frac{2}{3}}$ is $0$ at $0$, so the tangent line at $(0,0)$ is the $x$ axis.